# Automatically generate IJulia notebooks

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

Recently I learned, that using python it is possible to generate IPython notebooks [automatically](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/fperez/9716279). This looks like a cool feature and I would like to use it for some automatic report generation. However with julia instead of python.
So is there some clean/recommended way of automatically creating IJulia notebooks using julia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be posible to do this from Julia via the `PyCall` package:

- http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/Ismael-VC/4c4fcee41b8761af9673

However I got an exception at `Out [8]`. I've already opened a new issue for this:

- https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl/issues/164

Comment: Thanks very much for the effort! For the record, I face the same errors as you.

Comment: https://github.com/yuyichao/explore/blob/c33c4297493c930d3568c50cfcf57dcf8730abcf/julia/ijulia-generate/Generate.ipynb

Comment: @yuyichao, thanks, but does not work for me, when I run the last cell, I got the following error: PyError (:PyImport_ImportModule) <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>
ImportError('No module named builtins',)

Comment: Forgot to mention that this is on python3. The import of builtins is just to get the python `open` function. `@pyimport __builtin__` should probably work.

Comment: Cool, I replaced builtin by _ _builtin__ as you suggested and now it works!